# Unexpected form submit

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, post

I faced with a strange problem. I write ASP.NET web application. 
I have form tag on the aspx page and submit in the form. When I click on the submit form's data are posted. It is ok. But if I close the page right after submit and then re-open it with Main Menu -> Recent Tabs (I use Google Chrome) the form's submit fires once again and data are posted too. I would like to avoid this behavior because repeated posting data to server is unwelcome and unexpected. It happens after select Recent Tabs only (when  I prress Ctrl+Shift+T it does not happen) How could I prevent it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Check if it's a PostBack. If it is a PostBack then return.